# Password strength checker (Udemy course)

Tags: python

This program is a project out of Udemy course. Kindly request you to review my code and suggest insights to better it. It takes your password hashes (sha1) and then sends hashedpassword[:5] to https://haveibeenpwned.com/ website. Gets the response and checks whether our hashed password is present in the response got from the site

Thanks in advance!!

```
import requests
from ezhashlib import hashlib
import sys


def req_api_data(query_char):

   '''Returns response for pwned website after passing the tail'''
    url = 'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/' + query_char
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code!=200:
        raise RuntimeError(f'Error fetching: {res.status_code}, check the api and try again')
    else:
        return res


def get_pw_lead_count(hashes,hashes_to_check):

    hashes = (line.split(':') for line in hashes.text.splitlines())# Splits the responsex
    for h,count in hashes:
        if hashes_to_check == h:
                  return count
    return 0
       
def pwned_api_check(password):
    
    sha1password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8 ')).hexdigest().upper()
    # Generatng the sha1 for your password
    head,tail = sha1password[:5],sha1password[5:]
    res = req_api_data(head)
    #sending the head to website
    return get_pw_lead_count(res,tail)
    #Sending website response and tail for checking whether tail exists in the list of responses got from website.

def main():

    args=list(input().split())
    for passwords in args:
        count = pwned_api_check(passwords)
        if count:
             print(f"Change your \"{passwords}\" password as it's pwned {count} times")
        else:
            print("You've used a good password!!")



main()
```

Comment: @Marc I'd say there's not just no need for that, it's even *wrong*. If your password appeared in a breach, it's rather the fault of the breached site, not yours.

Comment: Calling this a "password strength checker" is misleading. It checks whether a website that you have used the password on was compromised, which has nothing to do with the strength of the password but rather with the security of the website that was cracked.

Answer (score 3):

### Use requests built-in validation

This:

```
if res.status_code!=200:
    raise RuntimeError(f'Error fetching: {res.status_code}, check the api and try again')
else:
    return res
```

should not raise manually; and should be replaced with

```
res.raise_for_status()
return res
```

### Hash checking

In `get_pw_lead_count`, `hashes_to_check` should be marked `: str`. Also, if `count` is a string - likely, since it comes from a `split()` - you should cast it to `int()` before returning it.

### Real arguments

```
args=list(input().split())
```

is not a standard way of retrieving arguments. Instead, use `argparse` and pass arguments via command line parameters.

It's also possible to retain `stdin` input as you have it, but you should in that case show a prompt.

### Indentation

Count the number of spaces for each of these lines:

```
    if count:
         print(f"Change your \"{passwords}\" password as it's pwned {count} times")
```

Each should be a multiple of four.

Answer (score 3):

### PEP8 conventions and formatting

You are already using F-strings in your code, so

```
url = 'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/' + query_char
```

could be:

```
url = f'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/{query_char}'
```

Spacing:

```
if res.status_code!=200:
```

should be:

```
if res.status_code != 200:
```

Ditto for:

```
for h,count in hashes:
head,tail = sha1password[:5],sha1password[5:]
etc
```

My suggestion is to use an IDE that has a linter plugin. For example Atom but there are alternatives. This will help enforce some habits. Strictly speaking, as per PEP8 conventions there should be 2 lines spacing between functions (or one within a class).

### request

The variable names are not always intuitive, for instance the function get_pw_lead_count expects a parameter named 'hashes', but it is in fact the request object from your other function.

This is a text parsing function basically, so rather than send a request object I would send request.text instead, that is the response. And the variable names should better reflect their purpose.

### Ergonomics

Good programs should be user-friendly and intuitive to use. So if you use the input function it would be good to add a prompt like this:

```
input("Enter one or more passwords, separated by whitespace: ")
```

Silent input is confusing. For the split function the default separator is any whitespace but an average user is not supposed to know the inner workings of your application. Clearly indicate what kind of input is expected.

### Import

It is a good habit to write Python scripts like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thus, your main function will be run if the file is executed as a script, but not if you **import** it. Because you may want to import the file (or any file) to reuse some of the functions it contains, but then it should not execute anything or interfere with the upstream code.

Comment: Wow thanks for reviewing the code. I'll try to implement the changes .